# SQLite 3 locking in PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, locking

I would like to lock an SQLite3 database, make a few queries, then unlock it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like the only way to do this with PHP < 5.3.3 is to use PDO. PDO seems to set the busy timeout by default to 60 seconds (as opposed to 0 set by SQLite3), and you can also set it explicitly with `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT, $timeout)` (same functionality as PHP 5.3.3's `SQLite3::busyTimeout()`).

Answer (score 6):

Existing answers are helpful but are missing pieces of the story.

You say you want to **lock the database, do some queries, then unlock it**.

If you're doing this because you don't want any other process to read the database while your changes are only partially completed, then you should know SQLite has a feature that makes this unnecessary: **transactions**.

With transactions, you can ensure that no other process sees your changes until they're complete, *but you don't have to lock the database while you're doing them*.  In fact, while you're making your changes, other processes can still read the parts of the database you're working on and to the other processess, *the database will continue to look as it did before you begin your changes*.

**How to do a transaction?**

1. Send a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` to the database.
2. Send your queries.
3. Send a `COMMIT` to the database (alternatively, the database will accept `COMMIT TRANSACTION` or even `END TRANSACTION` as synonyms).

**How does this magic happen?**

While the transaction is open, the database system maintains a second copy of everything you have modified on disk.  While this happens, other processes are free to read from the database.  When they come to a part of the data that you are modifying, they will see the version without any of your unfinished changes.  Once you end the transaction, the database system will mark your changed version as the official version and will no longer have to keep the other version.

The technical details of this differ between databases but all databases that support transactions will support equivalent functionality that ensures other processes do not see your unfinished changes.

**Your problem with other processes seeing errors**

Even though other processes can continue to read the database while you do your transaction, they will still be unable to write to it, and there will still be a very small window of time at the end of your transaction where they will have to wait to either read or write.  When they try to do so, they'll notice that the database is *locked*.

This is normal.  Unfortunately, PHP's implementation of SQLite3 (via both PDO and the SQLite3 class) does not wait to aquire the lock, it just halts with an error.  This default behaviour would be acceptable if you only ever expect a single client to access the database at a time, but not acceptable in a shared environment like a web server.

So, when opening an SQLite3 connection you should always set a busy timeout.  With PHP 5.3.3 you can do this with the busyTimeout() method of SQLite3, but if you don't have access to this for some reason you can do it with the following SQL query:

```
PRAGMA busy_timeout = 15000
```

It's in milliseconds, so that's 15 seconds.  This should work independently of your PHP version and whether you're using PDO or SQLite3 class.

Comment: Still presents a possible race condition as the next visitor's script is reacting to stale data instead of waiting for the fresh data to finish writing, no?

Comment: The database is responsible for consistency/atomicity at the transaction level.  No race condition can break the assurances that the database provides for a transaction: for the entire length of a transaction, the database visible to that transaction is in a consistent state unaffected by other transactions.

Now, databases can and do allow other connections/processes to read data while other transactions are happening, and since they are different transactions, that's ok - each still has a consistent, if different view of the state of the DB ... (cont)

Comment: @ThoraciusAppotite ... Importantly for what you want, transactions in an ACID compliant database provide *isolation* - even if separate processes/connections are accessing the database at the same time, what each one "sees" and the effect they have on subsequent transactions will be the same as if all the transactions were run sequentially.  This does mean that some blocking happens, where sometimes a transaction including writes has to wait for another transaction including writes to complete before beginning, to preserve this assurance.

Comment: (the above assumes full ACID compliance, including "serializable" level isolation - which SQLite does support, through locking)

Answer (score 4):

Sqlite has transactions, this sounds much like what you are looking for. See [here](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)

You essentially do somthing like this:

```
BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION
UPDATE users SET foo=1 WHERE id=42
UPDATE fish  SET bass=2, cod=3 WHERE id=42
END TRANSACTION
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that, after calling `BEGIN EXCLUSIVE TRANSACTION`, no other processes can either read or write until the `END TRANSACTION` query finishes?

Comment: If I do this, the other scripts fail with a PHP error while trying to read the locked db. There seems to be absolutely no way to make them wait until the lock is released, unless you either do some strange tricks to capture the error, or you use PHP 5.3.3.